# save a matrix as a file directly into database without saving initially to disk

Tags: java, mysql, database, file, matrix

I have a task where I need to store a matrix filled with data of 'double data type'for future use in a database.

Well, I can do it by initially saving it to a disk in a .txt file and then saving it as blob in the database.

Is it possible to save it directly to the database? It would increase the time efficiency a lot since I have a lot of matrix data to deal with.

If it is possible could anyone give me a slight idea.

Thanks.

What I'm doing right now is in the format as stated below:

```
void putaverage(double[][] average) throws SQLException {
        // from here is the part of saving the matrix in a text file
      try {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("average.txt"));

    for(int i=0; i<average.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<average[i].length; j++){

             writer.write(average[i][j]+" "); 
        }
       writer.println(); 
    }

    writer.flush(); 
    writer.close();        



   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {      
     e.printStackTrace();
   }

         //Now Im reading the text file and adding to database
        File imgfile = new File("average.txt");
          FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(imgfile);
           PreparedStatement pre =
           con.prepareStatement("insert into average 'averageimage' values(?)");

             pre.setBinaryStream(1,(InputStream)fin,(int)imgfile.length());
                 pre.executeUpdate();
                 System.out.println("Successfully inserted the average file into the database!");
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: Mureinik,I did it.

Comment: what problem with this code?

Comment: There's no problem sir, but I wish to know if there is any way of inserting into the database directly without having to write on disk.

Comment: With your code, you save the file bytes in a BLOB I guess. Instead of creating a file and reading it to put it in a Database BLOB, you could directly "serialize" your 2D array of double. You could write the dimension of the array and then the serie of double in a ByteArrayOutputStream and then save this Stream in a database BLOB.